# Как задать относительный путь для ссылки

Tags: c#, visual-studio

При добавлении в проект ссылки на dll путь к ней указывается полный:
`<Диск>:\<Папка1>\<Папка2>\<Папка решения>\<Название файла>.dll`
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать относительный путь типа `\<Папка решения>\<Название файла>.dll`, чтобы на другом компьютере эта ссылка корректно работала.

Comment: Что-то не замечал такого. Но можно руками слазить в `csproj` и поправить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо за подсказку, не знал, что в этом файле это нужно искать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, верное ли это место для указания пути?
`<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="<НАЗВАНИЕ ССЫЛКИ>">
      <HintPath>.\<НАЗВАНИЕ ССЫЛКИ>.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
.....`

Comment: Там вроде от папки с проектом считается... Или с solution'ом... Не помню.

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо. Разобрался, все теперь в норме.

Comment: Всегда можно получить текущую директорию (где *.exe файл лежит). Метод типа GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

Comment: Опубликуйте ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При добавлении ссылки на файл, расположенный в папке проекта, путь к ссылке указывается относительным. Этот путь можно увидеть в файле `csproj` в разделе:

```
<ItemGroup> 
<Reference Include="<НАЗВАНИЕ ССЫЛКИ>"> 
<HintPath>.\<НАЗВАНИЕ ССЫЛКИ>.dll</HintPath> 
</Reference> .....
```

Comment: И потом отметьте его как верный :).

Comment: @andreycha, собственный только через 2 дня можно отметить вроде